# Is there a way to create a scrolling banner with alert on campaign record page?

Tags: visualforce, scrolling

I have a requirement where  need to display an alert message as scrolling text on top of campaign record based on   custom date field. If the date range falls in 2 days then I need to show this message. How can I achieve this?

Here is the custom component I developed to show as alert:

```
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false">
<style>
h1
{
text-align:center;
color:white;
font-size: 40px;
   }
</style>
<apex:form >
<div style="background-color: red;width: 100%">
<marquee scrollamount="15"> <h1>
Campaign Ends in 2 days  ! </h1>
</marquee>
</div>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap what you need to display conditionally into a `<apex:outputPanel>` and use the `rendered`. Since you can use a formula inside of this attribute, you can do something like :

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!TODAY() + 2 >= Campaign.Date__c}">
    <div>...</div>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

You may have to adjust the date formula, but this is how you can display the banner.

Comment: `{!TODAY() + 2 >= Campaign.Date__c}` would suffice. Comparison operators are automatically Boolean, so no need to do an IF here.